# Mysql2: How do I read a bit column correctly?

Tags: ruby, mysql2

Mysql2 reads in bit columns as strings by default.

My schema:

[image]

In Ruby:

[image]

How do I read them as bytes?

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way to deal w/it in the Mysql library, but in my experience, strings are how Ruby deals with binary data.  The binary file reader methods do the same thing.

Check out the [`#unpack`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-unpack) method.  You can do stuff like:

```
[16] pry(main)> bytes = "\x00\x01\x02"
=> "\u0000\u0001\u0002"
[17] pry(main)> bytes.unpack('C*')
=> [0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd have expected Mysql2 to cast the bit into bytes by default. But it doesn't do that as of now (I'm using 0.3.16). What I ended up doing was to covert it into bytes myself:

`row[:can_sell].bytes => [0]`